# Can Firefoxe's web-ext utility be made to open an extension page on start with -u?

Tags: url, firefox, uuid, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

As far as I understand, each time an extension is reloaded, it gets a new `moz-extension://` URL with a new UUID. This makes it impossible to know the extension page URL I want to use with `web-ext run -u` in advance. This makes `web-ext` almost worthless for me because I have to (manually) open the page I need to run my tests on. If I knew the URL beforehand I could just pass it to `web-ext` and do everything completely automatically, and with a headless FF. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

After some fiddling I finally managed to have `web-ext` open a page with `moz-extension` schema on browser start.

The only way (that I found) to open this page with an extension context (and test the page correctly) and not as an ordinary `file://` is to use a `moz-extension://<internal UUID>/path/to/extension/page/from/extension/root` type URI to access it.

The problem is, as a temporary extension, it always has a different UUID that is not preserved between re-installs, so there is no way of telling `web-ext` to open an extension page via `-u` while using the defaults.

This is where [this helpful documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Testing_persistent_and_restart_features) comes in. It mentions the `extensions.webextensions.keepUuidOnUninstall` option in `about:config` that does exactly that. So a profile has to be created that has this option set to `true`, and used with `web-ext` `-p` option.

The next problem I had was that the page would silently fail to open. Apparently Firefox was attempting to open the page before the extension was installed. But `web-ext` has a `--pre-install` option that makes the extension (and its pages) available at start, so when it is enabled the page does open. Caveat 1 is that using `--pre-install` requires the extension to have an [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Testing_persistent_and_restart_features#What_is_an_add-on_ID) (this one is not the mentioned UUID generated by Firefox) that has to be set in `manifest.json`. Caveat 2, `--pre-install` disables extension auto-reloading on file change.

So my final solution was to:

1. With `firefox --manageProfiles`, create a separate profile  to test my extension
2. Proceed to set and save the `extensions.webextensions.keepUuidOnUninstall` `about:config` flag (do this without `web-ext` or with `--keep-profile-changes` otherwise)
3. In `manifest.json` add an id for the extension:

   ```
   "applications": {
     "gecko": {
       "id": "addon@example.com"
     }
   }
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   web-ext run -p <testing profile name> --pre-install -u moz-extension://<extension UUID>/path/to/extension/page.html
   ```

This starts Firefox with a temporary installation of your extension and opens the desired page.

If you know a better solution (e.g. one that does not disable the auto-reloading), your answer is very welcome.